# How to add or subtract in heredoc syntax?

Tags: php, string, operators, heredoc

I need the following setup:

```
<ul>
  <li>8</li>
  <li class="active">9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to do this with php heredoc:

```
$pos = $_GET["pagination"];
$pagination = <<EOD
<ul>
  <li>{$pos-1}</li>
  <li class="active">$pos</li>
  <li>{$pos+1}</li>
</ul>
EOD;
```

But I get error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "-", expecting "->" or "?->" or "{" or "[" in ...
```

The only other solutions I can think of is using multiple variables or a function in heredoc. I think there must be a straight forward way to achieve this.

Comment: That post doesn't tell how to directly execute _expressions_ in heredoc, like `eval` function. I already know that method.

Comment: Well that _is_ the method. Just wrap your expression in a little function.